# Using Swift function that a function that takes a generic sequence

Tags: swift, generics

I'm picking swift up now and the generics are pretty different than what I'm used to. What is the right way to do something like this?

```
func createThing<T, Seq: Sequence>(_ type: T.Type, _ block : @escaping (_ sequence: Seq) -> Void) where Seq.Element == T {
    // ...
}

enum MyEnum {
    case A
    case B
}

// error: generic parameter 'Seq' could not be inferred
createThing(MyEnum.Type, { sequence in

    for i in sequence{
        //...
    }
})
```

I would love to just supply a generic type parameter directly with `createThing<MyEnum>(...)` but that apparently isn't something Swift can do and generics seem to work pretty different for protocols than they do everything else.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `createThing`? Because I can't imagine how you would implement such a function. It might be that the thing you want to achieve can be done another way.

Comment: It's hard to get a representative snippet here. I'm implementing something like the Kotlin actor model as an excuse to try some stuff and I ran into this. createThing is really createActor and it returns an Actor that will use the block to process messages to its queue.

Answer (score 0):

`Seq` is part of the generic signature of the `createThing` function, which means that the compiler either needs to be able to infer this from the calling context, or be explicitly be told what concrete implementation of `Sequence` should expect. Also placing the `Sequence` generic at the function level really limits what you can do within that function, since it cannot instantiate a protocol.

You can convert the `(Seq) -> Void` block to a `(T) -> Void` one, and move the sequence iteration in `doSomething`, this will remove the compile error. And while you're at it, you can add a default value for the `type` parameter, this will enable type inferring and automatic filling of that parameter

```
func createThing<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, _ block: (T) -> Void) {
    // ...
    // assuming sequence is create above
    sequence.forEach(block)
}

enum MyEnum {
    case a
    case b
}

// a dedicated function for processing items also means better structured code :) 
func processEnum(_ value: MyEnum) {
    // do your stuff
}

// you can now pass only the second argument
createThing(processEnum)
```

Comment: This is pretty different from what I'm trying to do. `block` won't be executed right away, it will just be fed to a constructor of another class and it will be executed some time later. The sequence doesn't exist at this point either, but it will. I'd also like to give the caller the full sequence so it can be mapped/filtered freely.

You do hint at some alternatives though. Is there something I can do that would help the compiler correctly infer the type? In another language, I would have thought that having the type of `T` would be enough.

Comment: Still, somewhere down the line you will need to instantiate the sequence, and passing a protocol will kinda interfere with that. Basically the sequence type should not be enforced by the caller, as it happens in your code, it should be provided by the callee.

Comment: You made me realize that I actually do have a class that implements `Sequence` that I can use instead. I suppose I was trying to use the least specific type. If it were Java I would have returned a Collection rather than a LinkedList for example.